# How can i copy my static files to my output location in a typescript express project?

Tags: typescript, express

I am trying to copy my static files in my input directory to my output directory in express. I followed [this tutorial link](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/11/15/node-express-typescript) in which they used shell.js to copy the static files.

the code to copy the static file is in my CopyAssets.ts:

```
import * as shell from "shelljs";

shell.cp( "-R", "src/views", "dist/" );
```

and the script to call the command is in my package.json as :

```
 "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist/*",
    "copy-assets": "ts-node tools/CopyAssets",
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json --fix",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "build": "npm-run-all clean lint tsc copy-assets",
    "dev:start": "npm-run-all build",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch src -e ts,hbs --exec npm run ",
    "start": "node .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

after when i run an `npm run dev` it does not copy my scripts, why is this ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are in **dev** mode use [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node), it allows you to run TypeScript without transpiling.

I use [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) to execute my local installed dependencies.

Here is my *package.json* scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "npx rimraf ./build/ && npx rimraf ./log/",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "postbuild": "npx ts-node ./tools/build",
    "prod": "node ./app.js",
    "dev": "npx nodemon",
    "test": "npx jest --findRelatedTests"
}
```

To create a build folder with all your compiled .ts files and assets, type:

```
npm run build
```

**!!!** Using [npm scripts flavour](https://medium.com/yld-blog/using-npm-pre-and-post-hooks-d89dcf2d86cf):

**Before** build, npm runs `prebuild`, that perform a cleanse.

**After** build, npm runs `postbuild`, that copy all you assets and files inside your *./build* folder.

---

Here is the build.ts file that copy all assets and files:

```
import shell from 'shelljs';

const buildFolder = './build/';

const files = new Set(['.env', 'LICENSE', 'README.md', 'package.json', 'package-lock.json']);
const folders = new Set(['./src/views', './src/public']);

// Copy Files
files.forEach((file) => {
  shell.cp('-R', file, buildFolder);
});

// Copy Folders
folders.forEach((folder) => {
  shell.cp('-R', folder, buildFolder);
});
```